# Auto get data from database and show on html

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have table Post with this column `post_id`, `user_id`, `content`, `post_date`, `likes` and `comments`.

here is index.php

```
<?php
if ($select_post->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $select_post->fetch_assoc()) {
        $content = $row["content"];
        $user = $row["username"];
        $likes = $row["likes"];
        $cmt = $row["cmt_content"];
    }
} else {
    echo "Nothing!.";
}
?>
<div class="grid-container" id="gridContainer">
</div>
```

the function to add a new div tag to index.php

```
function addNewPost() {
    var title = document.getElementById('postTitle').value;
    var content = document.getElementById('postContent').value;

  
    var newPost = document.createElement("div");
    newPost.className = "grid-item";

    
    newPost.innerHTML = `
    <div class="grid-item">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/200" alt="Post Image">
        <div class="content">
            <p><?php echo $content ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="post-meta">
            <span class="like-count"><?php echo $likes ?></span>
            <button class="interaction-btn" onclick="likePost(this)"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></button>
        </div>
    `;

    document.getElementById("gridContainer").appendChild(newPost);

}
```

I want when I insert a new column to the table and reload the page a new post will be there. But there is no data shown

Comment: Where is the code where you are "actually" showing you `data`?

Comment: `index.php` starts by using an object `$select_post` that you have not instantiated!! You do understand that a PHP script and an HTML page is stateless i.e. maintains no variables between executions, dont you?

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is this: You don't need js, use your **data** directly inside *while loop*:

```
<div class="grid-container" id="gridContainer">
<?php
if ($select_post->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $select_post->fetch_assoc()) {
        $content = $row["content"];
        $user = $row["username"];
        $likes = $row["likes"];
        $cmt = $row["cmt_content"];
?>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/200" alt="Post Image">
        <div class="content">
            <p><?php echo $content ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="post-meta">
            <span class="like-count"><?php echo $likes ?></span>
            <button class="interaction-btn" onclick="likePost(this)"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></button>
        </div>
<?php
    }
} else {
    echo "Nothing!.";
}
?>
</div>
```